# Java algorithm: how to group entities

Tags: java, algorithm, collections, grouping

There are List of Entities: A, B, C, D.
Each Entity has their own list of another entities, lats say:

- A(1, 2, 3)
- B(4, 5, 6)
- C(1, 2)
- D(8, 9)

I need to group first level entities by intersection of elements of second level entities. In the end I should get something like:

```
List<Set<Entity1>>: 

 - A(1, 2, 3), C(1, 2)
 - B(4, 5, 6)
 - D(8, 9)
```

How can I write it in **java7**?

Comment: What's the logic of the grouping? is C with A because it list of numbers is included in that of A? what would happen with, say E(1,2,5,6)?

Comment: In initial situation, you have lists or sets?

Comment: @MauricePerry  elements (A, C) should be grouped in one list, because they have at least one similar element (but in example there are two: 1, 2)

Comment: @HansSchreuder in initial situation I have a list of elements(A, B, C...)

Comment: @Nikolas what would happen with, say E(1,2,5,6)? (two elements in common with A, two in common with B, two in common with C)

Comment: @HansSchreuder it will be group with (A, B, C, E) (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use some kind of lists, and compare them. 
The other option would be to use a real matrix, let's say rows are your entitites and columns are the numbers. use a X or 1 if the combination entity and number is true. Then walk through columns getting the matches (all columns having more than one element.)

For sake of simplicity, see listing (which is not very performant but does the job):

```
    HashMap<String, List<String>> entities = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    List<String> a = new ArrayList();
    a.add("1");
    a.add("2");
    a.add("3");
    List<String> b = new ArrayList<>();
    b.add("4");
    b.add("5");
    b.add("6");
    List<String> c = new ArrayList<>();
    c.add("1");
    c.add("2");
    List<String> d = new ArrayList<>();
    d.add("8");
    d.add("9");

    entities.put("A",a);
    entities.put("B",b);
    entities.put("C",c);
    entities.put("D",d);
    System.out.println("Check");
    entities.forEach( (entity, list) -> {
        entities.forEach( (otherEntity, otherList) -> {
            if (! entity.equals(otherEntity)) {
                // System.out.println(entity + otherEntity + list + " versus " + otherList);
                list.forEach(l -> {
                    otherList.forEach(o -> {
                        // System.out.println(" " + l + o);
                        if (l.equals(o))
                            System.out.println("hit:" + entity + " and " + otherEntity);
                    });

                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: But this is just identifying overlap, no "merging", right?

Comment: Right. I would like to leave some part of the implementation to the poster.

Comment: He said Java7 not Java8 :)

Comment: use a "for (Entity entity: entities)" construction instead of "foreach" and "->". Logic stays the same

Comment: I rewrite it with Java7, not an issue, thanks) Yes, we find matches. But how to group these matches to different sets?

Answer (score -1):

Not really an answer, but too short for comment...

I'm not sure if of requirements, but is this possible?

- A (1, 2)
- B (2, 3)
- C (3, 4)

and the result will be

- A, B, C

Not optimal algorithm will be (pseudo code)

```
1: initially each entity is a group
2: for each pair of group identify if there is intersection
3:     if there is, merge the groups
4:     if there is not you are done = you have groups
5: repeat the for loop while the group number is decreasing
```

It is not optimal, but might be a good start.

Detailed description for example above

1. you have groups `[ {A}(1, 2), {B}(2, 3), {C}(3, 4) ]`
2. you identify, that A and B have common "relation" - 2
3. you merge, new groups will be `[ {A, B}(1, 2, 3), {C}(3, 4) ]`
4. you continue and find, that first and second group have common relation - 3
5. you merge, new groups will be `[ {A, B, C}(1, 2, 3, 4) ]`

To simplify your implementation, you can have a list of related entities for group.

---

Example for new input - `[ {A}(1, 2), {B}(3, 4), {C}(1 ,3) ]`, I added line numbers to pseudo code

- we have 3 groups initially
- line 2 in pseudo code is 2 for loops basically, let say you identify A and C intersect
- in line 3 you merge to `[ {A, C}(1, 2, 3), {B}(3, 4) ]`
- line 5 in pseudo sends you back to line 2, you had 3 groups initially, you merged and number of groups decreased to 2
- you continue identify intersection and merge to just one group...

Comment: this solution is interesting. But imagine that we have initial groups: [{A}(1, 2), {B}(3, 4), {C}(1 ,3)]. When we will compare A and B there are no comparison and we divide their on different groups. But when we will compare A and C it will match, also B and C will match. I think how to handle this case

Comment: This is not a problem, every time you merge, you virtually start from scratch, identify intersection in new group of elements... You need O(n^3) member comparisons - in outer loop you merge let say just one pair and to find intersection you need to compare each pair...